# ASP.NET Passing asp:Repeater value to asp:Button CssClass attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, webforms

I have a payment method repeater that contains a button.  We have new button styles that need to be applied.  The new button style changes based on a `btnMode` setting in the database which is set to a string representing a CSS class selector.  The CSS works fine.

I put this in the ASPX page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" 
            runat="server" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" 
            CssClass='<%# Eval("btnMode") %>' 
            Text="edit" 
            CommandName="ChangePaymentProfile" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PaymentSourceId") + "|" + Eval("AuthNetPaymentProfileId")%>' />
```

In the ASPX.cs

```
    //Command Button Clicked: Change Payment Method
    else if (e.CommandName.ToLower().Equals("changepaymentprofile"))
    {
        hdChangeYN.Value = "Y";

        showAddPaymentForm();

        //display billing address of selected card
        hsParams.Add("CustomerId", User.Identity.Name);
        hsParams.Add("PaymentSourceId", strPaymentSourceId);
        DataTable dt = DbHelper.GetDataTableSp("234_accountAddress__ByPaySourceId", hsParams);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            tbFistName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToObjectString();
            tbLastName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToObjectString();
            inputAddress1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToObjectString();
            inputAddress2.Text = "";

            string strCountryCd = dt.Rows[0]["CountryCd"].ToObjectString();
            ddlCountry_Update(strCountryCd); //Update Country & State DDL because Country can be a foreign country

            ddlCountry.SelectedValue = strCountryCd;
            inputCity.Text = dt.Rows[0]["City"].ToObjectString();
            ddlState.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["StateProvinceId"].ToObjectString();
            inputZipcode.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Zipcode"].ToObjectString();

            ddlCardType.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["CardType"].ToObjectString();
        }
    }
```

When I load the page in the browser the `<%# Eval("btnMode") %>` does not get resolved to a value. I see this when I open the inspector:

```
<input 
    id="btnEdit" 
    class="<%# Eval("btnMode") %>"
    type="submit" 
    name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderFront$ContentPlaceHolderFront$rptList$ctl01$btnPrimary" 
    value="" 
    onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderFront$ContentPlaceHolderFront$rptList$ctl01$btnPrimary&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" >
```

It is important to point out that this attribute `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PaymentSourceId") %>'` does work, and `btnMode` does contain valid data.

Comment: Please show your `btnPrimary` binding method on code behind, probably you have data binding issue in code level that affects in page life cycle.

Comment: You are showing 2 different buttons. The aspx of `btnEdit` and the outputted html of `btnPrimary`. Which is it?

Comment: `btnEdit`. I actually have three buttons that need to be setup this way.  Question fixed.

Comment: I tried your `asp:Button` snippet. It worked as it should. I get the `Eval` equivalent class names in the HTML and no `onclick` event. Where does the `onclick` postback function come from on a `type="submit"` button?

Comment: Not all Asp.Net control properties are databindable. Only properties marked with the `BindableAttribute` can be databound. `CssClass` is not one of them it seems. See [BindableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CssClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @user1429080 I've looked at the links you provided, but I'm not seeing where it says that CssClass is not a BindableAttribute.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I've added the backend code.

Comment: Compare with the `Button`'s [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property. That IS decorated with `[BindableAttribute(true)]`, whereas `CssClass` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, not all properties in Asp.Net controls can be databound. `CssClass` is one that cannot be databound.

To get around this, you can add an `OnItemDataBound` event handler to the repeater where the `Button` is. In the event handler you can then user the `e.Item.DataItem` to get the value you want and set it as the `CssClass` on the button. Sample code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterTest" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterTest_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="TestButton" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("someText") %>'/>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var testData = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new { someText = "Button " + i.ToString() }).ToList();
    RepeaterTest.DataSource = testData;
    RepeaterTest.DataBind();
}
protected void RepeaterTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic foo = e.Item.DataItem;
    ((Button)e.Item.FindControl("TestButton")).CssClass = foo.someText;
}
```

Comment: This helped me, but `e.Item.DataItem.IsPrimaryDisplay` did not work for me. Rather, `DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "IsPrimaryDisplay").ToString()`. i.e. this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/1471443/1783439